# select from where id count in a sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table named **Groups** that have an **id** and **maxUsers**.

i also have a **Scores** table that have **id**, **groupId** and **userId**

i want to find a row in **groups** that have less than maxUsers rows with the same group id in **scores** and that non of the rows have the same **userid** as **?** input

so i assumed when ever i put the column **id** in the bottom query it will reffer to the id in the current **groups** row, i dont think that this is happening right now, is it possible to make it work like i intend? and is there a way to make it work more efficiently?

```
select id from Groups where 
(select count(1) from Scores where groupId = id) < maxUsers and 
(? not in (select userId from Scores where groupId = id)) limit 1;
```

Comment: Use `where groupId = groups.id`. Otherwise it treats it as `scores.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `id` in the subquery is interpreted as `Scores.id`, not `Groups.id`, you need to qualify it with the table name to override this.

But a better way is to use a `JOIN` with a grouped subquery.

You can use the `LEFT JOIN ... NULL` pattern in the subquery to filter out the groups that include the specified `userId`.

```
SELECT g.id
FROM Groups as g
JOIN (
    SELECT groupId, COUNT(*) AS grount
    FROM Scores AS s1
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT groupId
        FROM Scores
        WHERE userId = ?
    ) AS s2 ON s1.groupId = s2.groupId
    WHERE s2.groupId IS NULL
    GROUP BY groupId
) AS s ON g.id = s.groupId AND s.count < g.maxUsers
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: is join better even when using the ** limit 1** ?

Comment: Good question. I assumed the limit was just for the example, and it wouldn't be limited in the real query.

Comment: i think it can be hacked some how like this:
select id from Groups where 
(select sum(case when userId  = ? then 99999 else 1 end) from Scores where groupId = Groups .id) < maxUsers limit 1;

in this version there is only 1 subquery so i can assume it will be faster, yet i do not know what improvements mysql does under the hood so it might be not relevent as well

Comment: I've added the code to filter out `userId = ?`